# Prevent rbind from creating empty rows when handling numeric(0)

Tags: r

I find the behavior of `rbind` somewhat non-intuitive when it's provided with empty vectors. For example,

```
rbind(numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0))
# [1,]
# [2,]
# [3,]
```

produces a 3-by-0 matrix, while I would expect the output to be a consistent `numeric(0)` instead. While it may be fun to debate whether you get "one nothing" or "three nothings" when you add a "nothing" to itself three times, my question is whether it's possible to suppress this behavior? Alternatively, I am looking for another function that can "rbind" matrices, while also producing an object with no rows when none of the inputs have rows.

My approach so far has been to cast `numeric(0)` to a `matrix(0,0,0)`, which appears to work more consistently with `rbind`:

```
rbind(matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0))
# <0 x 0 matrix>
```

**High-level picture:** I have a function that accepts one or more matrices representing linear constraints, rbinds them as the first step and performs some downstream operations. The number of rows in the `rbind` output is taken to be the total number of input constraints. I discovered the above behavior when I was removing the last row in an input matrix and accidentally left off `drop=FALSE`, thus calling my function with a `numeric(0)` instead of a proper `matrix(0,0,0)` and getting the wrong total number of constraints, because `nrow(rbind(numeric(0)))` was returning 1.

Comment: The notion that you have 3 'nothings' if you rather call them so; is definitely correct. How else would yoou know the number of 'nothing' elements that were joined? In its abstract sense, you are binding three elements. That by itself indicates that one of the dimensions should be three. The other will depend on the number of elements within the vectors

Comment: @Onyambu However, `rbind(matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0))` returns a `matrix(0,0,0)` and, as pointed out below, `rbind(NULL, NULL, NULL)` returns `NULL`. To me, that's the intuitive behavior, and the behavior I would expect from rbinding multiple `numeric(0)`.

Comment: This is debateable. To me the intuition is still correct. Note that for matrix case, you are adding the dimension of the new matrix to the existing matrix. in this case, its 0+0 = 0.  For the NULL case, it definitely should be NULL. Note also that `as.matrix(numeric(0))` is not the same as `matrix(0,0,0)`. If you were to compare the matrix and vector, then `rbind(matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0))` should be compared to `c(numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0))`. ie with vectors, we areonly dealing with length, with matrix, we are dealing with dimensions

Comment: @Onyambu I would disagree. `as.matrix(numeric(0))` has zero rows and following your logic, 0+0=0, so the output matrix should also have zero rows. But you're right: `as.matrix(numeric(0))` is a 0-by-1 matrix, while `matrix(0,0,0)` is a 0-by-0 matrix. So, I am willing to adjust my expectation and say that `rbind(numeric(0), numeric(0))` should produce `as.matrix(numeric(0))`, not `numeric(0)` as I stated originally. And as exciting as this conversation is, it would be nice to find a workaround for this behavior that didn't involve casting corner-case input arguments.

Comment: `cbind(numeric(0L))` returns `as.matrix(numeric(0L))` while `rbind(numeric(0L))` returns `t(as.matrix(numeric(0L)))`. I would say that `rbind` is behaving consistently, even if it's not how you want. _In any case_, `rbind` is implemented in C, so there's not much to do beyond preprocessing the arguments, except maybe forking R and modifying the source code...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should expect there to be no rows. From rdocumentation, "numeric is identical to double (and real). It creates a double-precision vector of the specified length with each element equal to 0." So, I don't think it's accurate to say they are "nothings."

If you rbind NULL, which I think is closer to "nothing," you get no rows:

```
rbind(NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

returns

```
NULL
```

So, to answer the question, no I don't know how it would be possible to bind numeric and get no rows.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. My approach so far has been to cast `numeric(0)` to a proper `matrix(0,0,0)`, which appears to work more consistently with `rbind`. However, casting to `NULL` may be a good alternative.

Comment: It might be helpful to know where you're going with this to think of some ways out.

Comment: Updated my question with the high-level picture.

Answer (score 1):

From `?rbind`:

> For `cbind` (`rbind`), vectors of zero length (including `NULL`) are ignored unless the result would have zero rows (columns), for S compatibility.

I think it is reasonable, if your use case demands it, to write your own `rbind` analogue that handles zero-length vectors like 0-by-0 matrices instead of 1-by-0 matrices. Maybe something like this?

```r
rbind0 <- function(..., deparse.level = 1) {
  f <- function(x) {
    if (length(dim(x)) != 2L && (is.atomic(x) || is.list(x)) && length(x) == 0L) {
      x <- vector(typeof(x), 0L)
      dim(x) <- c(0L, 0L)
    }
    x
  }
  args <- c(lapply(list(...), f), list(deparse.level = deparse.level))
  do.call(rbind, args)
}
```

Errors are thrown in more cases, because these 0-by-0 matrices are subject to `rbind`'s checks for dimensional compatibility. For example:

```r
x <- matrix(rnorm(9L), 3L, 3L)
identical(rbind(x, numeric(0L)), x)
## [1] TRUE
rbind0(x, numeric(0L))
## Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  : 
##  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

You might consider that desirable behaviour, apart from the error message incorrectly referring to `integer(0L)` as a matrix. You can add more tests to avoid these errors (or throw different errors) in specific cases, but I don't know that it's worth it. Again, it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to @Onyambu and @MikaelJagan for an interesting discussion in the comments.

The discussion brought my attention to `as.matrix(numeric(0))`, which appears to be a great intermediate between `numeric(0)` and `matrix(0,0,0)` as it represents a 0-by-1 matrix and its number of rows is preserved by `rbind`:

```
rbind(as.matrix(numeric(0)), as.matrix(numeric(0)))
#     [,1]
```

A great solution for my high-level scenario is then to simply wrap each argument inside `as.matrix()` before passing all arguments to `rbind`.

```
# Row-count-preserving (rcp) rbind for use with matrix-like arguments
rcp_rbind <- function(...) do.call(rbind, lapply(list(...), as.matrix))
```

The new function behaves identically to `rbind()` for matrix arguments:

```
identical(    rbind(diag(2), diag(2)),
          rcp_rbind(diag(2), diag(2)))                 # TRUE

identical(    rbind(matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0)),
          rcp_rbind(matrix(0,0,0), matrix(0,0,0)))     # TRUE
```

while also solving my issue of extra rows being generated from empty vectors

```
rcp_rbind(numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0))
#      [,1]
```

(Note that additional modification are required to properly handle `deparse.level` if the function is to be extended beyond matrix-like objects, which is outside the scope here.)